# Pandas: Write CSV file with Windows line ending

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]})
df.to_csv('test.csv', line_terminator='\r\n')
```

gives the file

```
,A,B\r
\r\n
0,1,3\r
\r\n
1,2,4\r
\r\n
```

however, I would like to have

```
,A,B\r\n
0,1,3\r\n
1,2,4\r\n
```

How can I achieve this (i.e., `\r\n` instead of `\r\r\n`). My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Why don't you try `line_terminator='\n'`?

Comment: why should this matter? won't the thing that tries to open the file understand this format?

Comment: RFC 4180 specifies the line terminator CRLF: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: Your code works fine for me, windows 10, python 3.4 pandas 0.19.1

Comment: for me it does not, windows 10, python 3.5.2, pandas 0.19.1

Comment: Try this `df.to_csv('test.csv')` - without specifying the `line_terminator` parameter

Answer (score 1):

The following is from a submission to Kaggle. Hope you'll find it useful. I had to write the output loop myself as pandas insisted on adding both CR and LF and it caused problems for Kaagle.

```
import io

with io.open('../output/submission_{}.csv'.format('22-Sep-2018-Try-Something_with_re'), 'w', newline='\n') as of:
    of.write('fullVisitorId,PredictedLogRevenue\n')
    for ind in out_log.index:
       of.write('{},{}\n'.format(ind, out_log['PredictedLogRevenue'][ind]))
```

The main things to notice is the use of io.open, setting newline='\n' in the open call, and adding '\n' at the end of each write call.